# Cant test if a database boolean is true in Laravel

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent, orm

I am trying to query our database to see if users can log in based on whether the organisation they belong to have logins enabled.

LoginController.php

```
protected function redirectTo()
{
    $user = Auth::user()->id;
    $userOrg = UserOrganization::where('user_id', $user)->first();
    $org = Organization::where('id', $userOrg->org_id)->first();

    if ($org->allow_org_login == 0) {

        return '/login';
    } else {
        if(Auth::user()->has_changed_temp_password == false)
        {
            DB::table('users')->where('id', $user)->update(['last_login' => Carbon::now()]);
            DB::table('users')->where('id', $user)->increment('total_logins');
            return '/user/password/change';
        } else {
            DB::table('users')->where('id', $user)->update(['last_login' => Carbon::now()]);
            DB::table('users')->where('id', $user)->increment('total_logins');
            return '/overview';
        }
    }
}
```

trying to log in as a user belonging to an organisation with allow_org_login = 0 should redirect to the '/login' page, but instead it either logs the user in or prompts for a password change for a new user.

What am I doing wrong?

Edit: Debug contents of $org (allow_org_login on the bottom line)

[image]

Comment: can you provide more detail. i'm not really understand well what you want

Comment: did you try if ($org->allow_org_login == false) ?

Comment: what exactly the relation between user and organization? is it many to many with UserOrganization as pivot table?

Comment: @VivekChoudhary Yes, I tried with == false

Comment: @OMR yes, that's right. $org seems to be returning an instace of the correct organisation. I'll edit the question with the debug output

Comment: @sokhai What other info would be helpful? I am happy to provide any details. I'm not very experienced with Laravel. I usually use Django, to me this feels like it should work.

Comment: @JimiWindmills I guess you will need to logout user before `return '/login';` as the logged in user can not be routed to login page again if user already logged in.

Comment: I guess your code is working in this style `user(id, pass)->login->check if origination access->if no goto login->else change pass or goto overview`

Answer (score 0):

since there is many to many relation between user and organization.
i suppose this relation is defined in User & Organization  as in documentation:

https://laravel.com/docs/7.x/eloquent-relationships#many-to-many

considering that:

user may have more than an organization, and if any of the organization allowed log_in the user should login to your system

```
$user = Auth::user();
$userOranization=$user->organizations()->get();
$allowUserToLogin=false;
if($userOranization->where('allow_org_login',1)->first()!=null)
$allowUserToLogin=true;
```

and then:

```
if ($allowUserToLogin == 0) {

        return '/login';
    } else {  ....
```

Comment: This still takes me through the conditional and lands me at the login page

Answer (score 0):

for redirectTo() method it will only fire when we using POST method for login.

inside you redirectTo() method your check condition and then you return '/login'; 
which it will redirectTo login page. but this time you already login then on login it will check if user login then it redirectTo url that we config on LoginController and protected $redirectTo; it will not call redirectTo() method. cuz this time we use redirect using GET method not POST.

if you want to put validate on redirectTo() method you can try below code:

```
protected function redirectTo()
{
    $user = Auth::user()->id;
    $userOrg = UserOrganization::where('user_id', $user)->first();
    $org = Organization::where('id', $userOrg->org_id)->first();

    if ($org->allow_org_login == 0) {
        Auth::logout(); // logout user before redirect
        return '/login';
    } else {
        if(Auth::user()->has_changed_temp_password == false)
        {
           // depend on you choice need to logout or not
            DB::table('users')->where('id', $user)->update(['last_login' => Carbon::now()]);
            DB::table('users')->where('id', $user)->increment('total_logins');
            return '/user/password/change';
        } else {
            // depend on you choice need to logout or not
            DB::table('users')->where('id', $user)->update(['last_login' => Carbon::now()]);
            DB::table('users')->where('id', $user)->increment('total_logins');
            return '/overview';
        }
    }
}
```

but for my option i will create new middleware for handle this.